# string sieving with python

Tags: python, string, parsing, split

Assume you get a string. Example:

```
s = "FishCatRainComp_CatWater_JamDog"
```

And you define a sieve. A sieve - is a list of words you would like to catch up(once if multiple occurrence in s), for example:

```
sieve = ["Dog","Cat"]
```

Passing a string through a sieve should produce a string, in our case that would be:

```
out = "CatDog"
```

What would be the most elegant way to achieve the result?

Comment: Your simple way suggests that the input should in fact be `"DogCat"` (and not `"CatDog"` as you've mentioned).

Comment: @barakmanos good point, will fix this

Comment: In any case, you could use `''.join([word for word in sieve if word in s])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the most elegant way that comes to mind:

```
''.join([word for word in sieve if word in s])
```

---

Given that the order of the words in the input string should be reflected in the output string:

```
def SieveString(s,sieve):
    zipped = zip(sieve,[s.index(word) for word in sieve if word in s])
    zipped.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
    return ''.join(word for word,index in zipped)
```

Comment: That will produce `"DogCat"` for the sample op posted above. Not `"CatDog"` which is the correct answer.

Comment: @Omada: See my comment to the question, which originally provided a coding example giving the same output, and asked for a more elegant manner of doing it.

Comment: @Omada nice catch. Perhaps barak should iterate through sieve backwards with sieve[::-1]

Comment: @MarkHannel No. That would reverse the whole string.

Comment: @barakmanos I think you are misunderstanding how a sieve is supposed to work. The output should have the words in the same order as they appeared in `s` (at least as far as my understanding is)

Comment: @Omada: I think you are missing my point. The question **originally** gave a coding example which resulted in **this** output (`"DogCat"`), asking for a more elegant manner. I notified OP about that (since he/she also mentioned the output `"CatDog"`), and answered it as is. The OP has later removed the original coding example.

Comment: @Omada: In any case, I've added a solution referring to this ("new") restriction.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the order of the strings as they appear in `s`, you could do something like this:

```
found = re.findall('({})'.format('|'.join(re.escape(w) for w in sieve)), s)
```

You would then have to [remove the repeated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-whilst-preserving-order):

```
def remove_repeated(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]

print(''.join(remove_repeated(found)))
```

This solution might be longer, but it has better asymptotic behaviour

You could otherwise sort the string by their `index`:

```
>>> sorted([word for word in sieve if word in s], key=lambda word: s.index(word))
```